# Laravel Regular Expressions differs in tinker from web

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-artisan

Getting crazy at the moment ! I've got a simple regex which is behaving differently If I test it in artisan tinker shell and if I do it via web. 
My environment  NGINX + php-fpm

Let me explain :

The code quite simple

`Log::debug($txt);
$found = preg_match(Util::$EXTRACT_PATTERN, $txt, $matches);`

I dump $txt to log so I can copy it and take it to shell artisan tinker to do exactly :

`//Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 5.6.16-2 — cli) by Justin Hileman
$txt = <copied_text_from_log>
$found = preg_match(Util::$EXTRACT_CIF, $txt, $matches);`

Well, in shell tinker it matches and in web it does not :(
So, desperate, I've checked following things are the same in both environments:

- PHP 5.6.16-2
- PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
- PCRE Library Version => 8.35 2014-04-04

The only difference I see is the expected ISAPI (cli and fpm-fcgi) which I do not think can make any difference on its own, independently of extensions.

Please help I've spent nearly 8 hours squeezing my brain with this :(

As requested, to help answers, pattern, txt and results are

`public static $EXTRACT_PATTERN = 
'/^.*([a-z|A-Z]{1}[-|\s]?[0-9][0-9][0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})+.*/is'
//
$txt='CAMINO ASTIGARRAGA, 2 OIARTZUN 20180 B-20987541 Factura 2107-T2-2 Fecha: 05/04/2017 Vence: 05/05/2017 #CONCEPTOPVP. UNIDADCANTIDADTOTAL 1dsa 23.000 ?32736 ? 2213dsa213sa 0.000 ?30 ? SUBTOTAL736 ? IVA 21%+ 154.56 ?'`

And results are in tinker

`>>> $matches[1]
=> "B-20987541`

and  empty array() in web environment

Comment: I think you'd do yourself a favour by including the regex pattern and value of the variable you're applying the regex to in your question. You should also share with us the differing results you have in both tinker and on your live site.

Comment: Try with the `/\b[a-z][-\s]?[0-9]{7}[a-z0-9]\b/ui` pattern and see if you get the correct values in `$matches[0]`. Note the `u` is there only if your input may be a Unicode string (containing, e.g. letters like `Ę` or `ł`).

Comment: The mistery of REGEXPs. No  man :(. Thanks, but now, formerly successful cases fail matching bigger chunks of txt, instead of just the numeric code I seek for.  The main thing for me is **what is different in 2 environments?**

Comment: The input is bigger, I believe, and that causes issues. Your regex matches *the last* value captured with the capturing group. So, perhaps, the best approach will be using my pattern with `preg_match_all` and get the last item only.

Comment: nope  :(  My regex (simplified, thanks to u, as it came from another one where I needed other extractions) keeps working better, though not 100% fine.  I'll keep breaking my mind